# Stopping a countdown on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set a function to start counting down from 25 minutes upon clicking a button. I was also able to make it reset back to 25 minutes when clicking the Reset button, but it continues counting down. How do I make it so that when the Reset button is clicked the text reverts back to 00:25:00 and stays there until Go is clicked again?

**JavaScript:**

```
function count() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours(pieces[0]);
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newtime;
    setTimeout(count, 1000);
}

$("#go").click(function() {
    count();
})

$("#reset").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "00:25:00";
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4w967gfp/4/). Thanks!

Comment: just a suggestion, this wouldn't fix your error but, if you are using jquery, you can always use `$("#time").html("00:25:00")` for the last line

Comment: Thanks, it looks much better with jQuery! @NevilleNazerane

Comment: no probs. You can do the same on the first line too `var startTime = $("#time").html()`,



there is yet another line before the setTimeout... but well you get the idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clear your `setInterval` call with [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval):

```
var clr;
function count() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours(pieces[0]);
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newtime;
    clr=setTimeout(count, 1000);
}

$("#go").click(function() {
    count();
})

$("#reset").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "00:25:00";
    clearInterval(clr);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4w967gfp/14/)**

```js
var clr;

function count() {
  var startTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
  var pieces = startTime.split(":");
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(pieces[0]);
  time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
  time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
  var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
  var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newtime;
  clr = setTimeout(count, 1000);
}

$("#go").click(function() {
  count();
})

$("#reset").click(function() {
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "00:25:00";
  clearInterval(clr);
})
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat';
 body {
  background-color: bisque;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.container-fluid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.absolute-center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#tomato {
  background-color: #D72028;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 8px solid #A01C20;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
#reset {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #EB4539;
  /*border: 1px solid #A01C20;*/
  border: none;
  color: bisque;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-right: 5;
}
#reset:active {
  background-color: #d63a2f;
}
#go {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #EB4539;
  /*border: 1px solid #A01C20;*/
  border: none;
  color: bisque;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#go:active {
  background-color: #d63a2f;
}
#gores {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 60%;
  z-index: 10;
}
#time {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 38%;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #FFFFD7;
  z-index: 10;
}
#title {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #691112;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#desc {
  text-align: center;
  color: #691112;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <h3 id="title">Pomodoro</h3>
  <p id="desc">Welcome to Pomodoro Timer! Press go to start counting down from 25 minutes, or set it to whatever time you need.</p>


  <div id="tomato" class="absolute-center">
    <h1 id="time" class="absolute-center">00:25:00</h1>

    <div id="gores" class="absolute-center">
      <button id="reset">reset</button>
      <button id="go">go</button>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Good, but you forgot restart counting after clearInterval.

Comment: @WaldemarIce restart after clearInterval? What do you mean?

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use clearTimeout() to cancel a setTimeout. You'll need to save your timeout in a variable and reference it from reset.

```
var timer;
function count() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours(pieces[0]);
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newtime;
    timer = setTimeout(count, 1000);
}

$("#reset").click(function() {
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "00:25:00";
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Also note that currently you can click Go again while the timer is running, and you'll run out the clock twice as fast. You might want to disable the Go button while the clock is going

Comment: You also forgot restart counting, call count(), after clearInterval.

Comment: @WaldemarIce The OP doesn't want the count to restart. That's the whole point of the question

Comment: Good idea on disabling the Go button!

Answer (score 1):

```
var timerId;

function count() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours(pieces[0]);
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newtime;
    timerId = setTimeout(count, 1000);
}

$("#go").click(function() {
    count();
})

$("#reset").click(function() {
    clearTiemout(timerId);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "00:25:00";
    count();
})
```

Comment: If you call count() again, you'll start the timer again. There's also a typo with clearTimeout

Comment: This might not work as expected due to the pseudo recursive `setTimeout()` calls made.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `setTimeout(count,1000)` you need to keep the reference to the timeout ID. Store that value in a higher level variable and after you reset the clock call `clearTimeout(ID)`

Here's an [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/208sk8z1/)

Answer (score 1):

When `setTimeout()` is used with a pseudo recursive approach togenerate timed intervals `clearTimeout()` might not be useful. But instead you might do as follows.

```js
var reset = false;

function count() {
  var startTime = timeDisplay.textContent;
  var pieces = startTime.split(":");
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(pieces[0]);
  time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
  time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
  var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
  var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
  timeDisplay.textContent = newtime;
  !reset ? setTimeout(count, 1000) : timeDisplay.textContent = "00:25:00";
}

goButton.onclick = function() {
  reset = false;
  count();
}

resetButton.onclick = function() {
  reset = true;
}
```

```html
<div id="tomato" class="absolute-center">
  <h1 id="timeDisplay">00:25:00</h1>
  <div id="gores" class="absolute-center">
    <button id="resetButton">reset</button>
    <button id="goButton">go</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the timeout to a variable in the outer scope, you can use clearTimeout to stop it.

```
var countdownRunner; // added this

function count() {
    var startTime = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
    var pieces = startTime.split(":");
    var time = new Date();
    time.setHours(pieces[0]);
    time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
    time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
    var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
    var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = newtime;
    countdownRunner = setTimeout(count, 1000); 
}

$("#go").click(function() {   
    count();
});

$("#reset").click(function() {
    clearTimeout(countdownRunner);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "00:25:00";    
});
```